# Is ConcurrentDictionary ContainsKey method synched?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

Simple question
Assume that i have a `ConcurrentDictionary`

I use `TryAdd` and `ContainsKey` methods

Now assume that from 100 threads i started to process stuff. Assume that when 3 threads while adding a new key with `TryAdd` method another 3 threads asking whether key exists or not with `ContainsKey` method

**Do `ContainsKey` wait those 3 threads adding process before returning me result ?**

Or they are not synched i mean that one of those 3 threads could be adding the key i am asking with ContainsKey method however since the process is not done yet the answer i was gonna get would be false

Ty very much for answers C# WPF .net 4.5 Latest

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"No" (see Sam's comment), *furthermore* there is **no** atomic guard established by `ContainsKey` across other access or method calls to the ConcurrentDictionary.

That is, the following code is *broken*

```
// There is no guarantee the ContainsKey will run before/after
// different methods (eg. TryAdd) or that the ContainsKey and another
// method invoked later (eg. Add) will be executed as an atomic unit.
if (!cd.ContainsKey("x")) {
  cd.Add("x", y);
}
```

and the `Try*` methods should be used consistently instead

```
cd.TryAdd("x", y);
```

If further synchronization (or atomicity) needs to be guaranteed past the specialized concurrent methods then a larger monitor/lock context should be established.

Comment: -1: I interpreted the question to in bold to read "Does `ContainsKey` contain a synchronization call that will cause it to wait until the calls to `TryAdd` complete before returning its answer?" The answer to this question is "no". Concurrent collections are very different from collections which use locking for synchronization; they avoid locking wherever possible, typically by employing [lock-free or wait-free algorithms](http://rethinkdb.com/blog/lock-free-vs-wait-free-concurrency/).

Comment: @280Z28 A good observation. I've updated the initial wording with respect to the comment. Also, as supporting reasoning, `ContainsKey` uses TryGetValue internally (ref. [ConcurrentDictionary.cs from grepcode](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary@cs/1305376/ConcurrentDictionary@cs)).

Comment: I removed my -1 vote, but left the comment in place since it's referenced. Here's a better link: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#382

Comment: Even TryAdd can fail if you're counting on containsKey to tell you if the key exists from a potentially previously deleted key.  The concurrentdictionary gets into a state where it thinks the key doesn't exist, and whether or not it does, it can't add the same key. This seems horribly broken.

Comment: @nixkuroi Switching `TryAdd` for `Add` in the "broken" case is broken for the exact *same* reason: there is a race condition between the two method calls. The concurrent methods are only *individually* atomic. Failure to use the API correctly will result in code that is *not* thread-safe and results in behavior which, at first, may appear to be "horribly broken".

Comment: @nixkuroi However, at no time does the ConcurrentDictionary's internal state become corrupt. The result of TryAdd should be checked to ensure if the particular key was added; any larger atomic contexts must be guarded by other means such as locks.)